# Rest client update

Tags: c#, restsharp

When RestClient got updated, many functions top[ped working form the RestSharp library plugin.

I have been looking for what replaced the .Timeout function and Method.Post function. These functions were used in version 106 which cannot be used anymore since the update occurred

Please help!!

Comment: Most of the ClientOptions are moved to RestClientOptions. See this link for migration notes: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107